# Failed to map to class with member objects when used with Lombok

Tags: lombok, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper

The `Task` class has an instance of `TaskPayload` as a member object.

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Task {
    private int id;
    private TaskPayload payload;
    // skipping other members
}

@Data
@Builder
public class TaskPayload {
    private PayloadType payloadType;
    private PayloadEncoding payloadEncoding;
    private String data;
}
```

I am trying to insert a `Task` element to the table `task_queue` and return the inserted element.

```
    <select id="save" parameterType="com.prod.transponder.entity.Task" resultMap="taskResultMap">
        INSERT INTO task_queue(
            payload_type,
            payload_encoding,
            payload_text
        )
        VALUES
            (
                #{payload.payloadType},
                #{payload.payloadEncoding},
                #{payload.data}
            )
        RETURNING *
    </select>

    <resultMap id="taskPayloadMap" type="com.prod.transponder.model.TaskPayload">
        <result column="payload_encoding" property="payloadEncoding" />
        <result column="payload_type" property="payloadType"/>
        <result column="payload_text" property="data"/>
    </resultMap>

    <resultMap id="taskResultMap" type="com.prod.transponder.entity.Task">
        <id column="id" property="id"/>
        <association property="payload" resultMap="taskPayloadMap"/>
    </resultMap>
```

But when I test this I get the following error;

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.executor.result.ResultMapException: Error attempting to get column 'id' from result set.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.prod.transponder.constants.PayloadType.2
```

2 is the autogenerated Id of the inserted element.

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is not intuitive enough to solve this issue. The actual problem lies with Lombok's annotations. Mybatis is using `Reflection` to set values to fields. It needs a no-argument constructor (or no constructor at all) to map the values of the member object. So adding the `@NoArgsConstructor` annotation on top of the `TaskPayload` should solve the problem. But since `@Builder` requires a constructor with all members, one must add `@AllArgsConstructor` also. Hence modifying `TaskPayload` like this will fix the issue;

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TaskPayload {
    private PayloadType payloadType;
    private PayloadEncoding payloadEncoding;
    private String data;
}
```

Also, defining the `resultMap` is unnecessary here. Setting `Task` as `resultType` should work aswell.